# Understanding the formula for variance

Tags: statistics, expectation, variance

I have read both my textbook and the wikipedia page but there is a nuance about the notation that I am lost about.

The variance is defined as:

$E((X-\mu)^2)$

Assume we are on a finite case.

Does that mean that the expansion is:

$\sum (x_i-\mu)^2p(x_i)$

Or:

$\sum (x_ip(x_i)-\mu)^2$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want the average squared deviation. First compute the average $\mu$ by the usual formula:

$$ \mu = \sum_{x \in \Omega} xp(x) $$

if $X$ is a discrete random variable, or

$$ \mu = \int_{\Omega} x \ dF(x) = \int_{\Omega} x f(x) \ dx $$

where $f$ is the density and $F$ is the CDF.

Once you have this, you'll now find the deviations $x - \mu$, square them all, and find their average. That is, you'll compute

$$ \sigma^2 = \sum_{x \in \Omega} (x - \mu)^2p(x) $$

which gives the variance. (A similar formula is available for continuous random variables.) I challenge you to use this to derive the shortcut formula $\sigma^2 = E(X^2) - \mu^2$ where $E(x^2)$ is the average of the squares!

Answer (score 3):

It means the first one. In general for the discrete case for a function $g$ of the random variable $X$

$$
\mathbb{E}[g(X)] = \sum_i g(x_i)p(x_i)
$$

if you replace $g(X) = (X - \mu)^2$, then

$$
\mathbb{E}[(X -\mu)^2] = \sum_i (x_i -\mu)^2p(x_i)
$$

Answer (score 2):

The first one is correct.

$$E[(X-\mu)^2]= \sum (x_i-\mu)^2p(x_i)$$

If we approach expectation values as weighted sums, we point-wise multiply a weight $w(x_i)$ against the distribution $p(x_i)$ and then sum. This fits the form above.

$$E[w(X)]= \sum w(x_i)p(x_i)$$

Note that your second example results in

$$\begin{align}
\sum (x_ip(x_i)-\mu)^2 &= \sum x_i^2p(x_i)^2 - 2\mu\sum x_ip(x_i) + \mu^2\sum 1 \\
&= \sum x_i^2p(x_i)^2 - 2\mu E[X] + N\mu^2
\\
&= E[X^2p(X)] - 2\mu E[X] + N\mu^2
\end{align}$$

where the first term involves the expectation value of $X^2p(X)$ and I assume the sum runs from $i=1$ to $N$.